# Adding LaTex to title, label etc. with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am using the following code

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
  s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
  ax.plot(t, s)

   ax.set_xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
   ax.set_ylabel('\\textit{Velocity (\N{DEGREE SIGN}/sec)}', fontsize=16)
   ax.set_title(r'\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty'
         r'\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!', fontsize=16, color='r')
   plt.show()
```

which should be a working example and is taken from the matplotlib website.

I am running this on Windows 10 with Jupyter notebook (6.0.0, ipython 7.6.1) and Python 3.7.3 and I get the following error:

```
  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'kpsewhich: warning: running with administrator privileges\r\nC:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm'
```

which I think has to do with folder accessing on Windows i.e. Windows uses

```
C:\folder\folder\...
```

I thought the issue is with the line

```
 matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

so I went into the matplotlibrc file and just manually set usetex to True but I still get an error and cannot get the example to display. Is this a known Windows issue? Jupyter issue maybe? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: It looks like you are running python as admin, which results in a warning for kpsewhich. Can you try without admin priviledges?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when I try without admin privileges I get the error: "Unfortunately, the package iftex could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\latex.log" When I check the log there is a "Permission denied" error which makes sense since I am not running in admin mode. From what I can tell the 'iftex' package is already installed in MikTex (I updated the packages and refreshed the file name database as admin just in case)

Comment: You need to make sure the packages are available *without admin permission*.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not 100% sure how to do that. I removed the package and tried to re-install but did not get the option to "Install for everyone on this computer". The only option I get is for me as a user. Then  I changed the settings in MikTeX to not install on the fly but to ask me. When I run the code now I get asked to install the package and the permission error occurs. I guess that means the package is not installed locally? Also to make the packages available without admin permission do I have to re-install MikTex so that it's not an admin installation?